# Excel Add-In Configure Variables and Save

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, add-in

I have been asked to create an Excel Add-in for people to load a series of xml documents into Excel spreadsheets from Excel. I will write an add-in and publish its location for people to download their own local copies for use. I would Ideally like to have some constants for the VBA configurable by each end user, to customize their experience and function.

I thought it would be nice to have one button to run the Add-in and another button called "Configure" or something, which would edit the values of some of the variables in the VBA, and save the new values so that next time the user open Excel, the Add-in remains configured for them. Is anything like this possible and do you have some suggestions about what path I should follow to get there?

Is there any way to get the variables to persist? I guess I would need to save the values somewhere on the local version of the Add-in, but if so, what is the best way to store a set of parameters?

Any general advice would be most welcome; I have not actually written the add-in yet, being still in the design stages.

Comment: Addins are created as Excel workbooks, so it will have its own worksheets that it can reference.  Make sure that when you reference them in the add-in code, you use `ThisWorkbook` for the add-in's sheets, and that you use `ActiveWorkbook` for the end user's Excel sheets.  Then just store your variable values in cells, and you can change those cell values in the add-in worksheets to make them persistent.

Comment: That sounds like a perfect solution - I did not realise that they had accessible sheets in this way; all the stuff I read was saying "make sure to use ActiveWorkbook". I shall do as you suggest. If you repost this as an answer, I will mark it as such.

Comment: You can use the registry (assuming Windows) or a separate text file ("ini"-style or maybe XML)  If you use the add-in's worksheets to store data then you need to consider how you manage updates: you can't just publish a new version without your users needing to re-configure their settings.

Comment: I was too quick to accept - that's a really good point about publication; saving outside the add-in sounds a much better idea, although writing to the registry is likely to scare anyone who hears about it; call it a knee-jerk reaction, but people seem to blanch when they hear you are "mucking about with" the registry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not advise using cells to store settings as the user may F it up.

However VBA does support Registry edits.

```
SaveSetting "Macro name", "Settings", "Username", "John Doe"
```

The above code will save a setting or registry key called `Username` with the name `John Doe` in the appname called `Macro name` and the section `Settings`.

So in short you only need to change the last two strings when you save new settings. The first two should (to make it easy for you) be the same all the time.

The keys will be stored in : HCU\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings\Your app name\

To get the setting you use:

```
GetSetting("Macro name", "Settings", "Username")
```

Another solution is to use txt-file.
It's still better than cells but not as good as above mentioned registry.

```
settings = "Username=John Doe, Worktitle=Janitor"
MyFile = "C:\myapp\settings.txt"
fnum = FreeFile()
Open MyFile For Output As #fnum
Print #fnum, settings
Close #fnum
```

Now you have a txt file with the settings that you can read and parse.

Comment: I know that people around me will be very wary of anything that writes to the registry and I will therefore take the suggestion to use a text file for storing parameters; this seems a good compromise of perfect solution and keeping people happy by maintaining a simple and low risk strategy. If anyone is interested in how to read from a text file, there are many places on the web, including http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/read-data-from-text-file.html

Comment: If people get scared that you write stuff to the registry then tell them to mind their own business. They obviously are people that think something, but they don't. **The vba registry function can only write to a specific folder in the registry**. It does not have unlimited access. I believe the about 90-95% of all software you have installed on your computer writes to the registry. So unless you are a very untrusthworty person I don't see why your friends would feel scared. The txt way of doing it is as I wrote OK, but you still have the risk of someone "wanting to test something"

Comment: In the registry, only a few people know how to navigate to the correct path and very very few are willing to manipulate the data there. Thus, what you put in there stays.

Answer (score 0):

This page came up for me in Google as the first result for "excel vba global addin settings", but it doesn't address my specific case.

Based on the previous answers and comments, there are three ways an addin can store data, which can be used for things like settings... [On an internal sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640975/excel-add-in-configure-variables-and-save#comment64665169_38640975), or [in the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640975/excel-add-in-configure-variables-and-save#comment64665611_38640975), or [in a separate file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640975/excel-add-in-configure-variables-and-save/38641306#38641306). They each have their merits but your use case will determine which is the most appropriate.

Because its been a while since anyone contributed to the page, I'll discuss various scenarios, which might help someone else who lands here. In short, use an internal sheet if you don't need to provide users with a way to alter settings; use the registry if you're storing simple data types or the setting is personal to the user; or use a separate file if the data is complex or should be accessed as a global setting affecting multiple users.

TL;DR:

Storing on an internal sheet is useful because the VBA functions you design to Get and Set the settings will operate like any other functions you create that read/write data to/from a sheet (the code will subsequently need to save the addin file itself in order for changes to persist to a new session). This may be all that's needed if you're only making the addin for yourself, or you're not providing users with a way to alter settings. However, as noted by @Tim Williams, if you want to provide users with the ability to alter settings, you need to give serious consideration to how to distribute updates that don't overwrite those settings. Storing data outside of the addin becomes the only realistic way to do this.

Storing in the user's local registry isn't as scary a prospect as a novice might imagine. As demonstrated by @Andreas, VBA provides the functions GetSetting, SaveSetting and DeleteSetting to make this nice and simple. Just treat them as you would any other VBA function and trust that VBA is doing whatever is needed in the background, no need to know anything about how the registry works. Because of the simplicity of this option, it will suit the storage needs of most addins. Just don't expect to be able to store complex data this way, simple datatypes like String, Long and Boolean only. An important limitation to understand with this method is that this data will only be accessible by users individually.

You can store data of any type in a file, and it's a far more sensible option for storing complex data. And again, VBA provides all the functions necessary to Open and Close a file for reading or writing data as @Andreas' example shows, although the process is a good deal more clunky than the registry option IMO.

If your addin is designed to be used by a team, you might want to store the addin itself on a shared drive. A primary reason for doing this is to ensure that all users are using the same version of an addin at any given time. Updating that one file effectively 'pushes' any updates to them instead of having to rely on them downloading and installing new updates to your addin. In this scenario your addin can also leverage different 'types' of settings.

In an addin I'm working on at the moment there's a toast feature, and I want to give individual users a way to customise the colour, screen location, duration etc. I'm saving these settings in the user's local registry. You could use a file instead as mentioned above, but if you're doing this make sure you store the file in a responsible location, local to the user, not accessible by the team as a whole. These settings I call 'user' settings.

Another feature of my addin recognises and formats specific reports. I want to give the team a way of adding the details of new reports to be handled by this feature. Once a report has been added by a user, all users should be able to use the feature for that new report. These settings I call 'global' settings. It's this aspect I was researching that brought me to this page.

As it happens, using an addin's internal sheets for storage becomes relevant again in this context. Having a single addin file accessible on a shared drive means its not being distributed, even though multiple users are using it. So, if a user adds the details of a new report, those settings can simply be saved to the internal sheet and all users will be able to access them. Providing that when you want to make code updates you do them to the 'live' addin while 'in place', this could be a viable option. Ultimately though, even in a team scenario, you will probably want to develop the addin using a separate file to the live addin, for backup and versioning reasons at least, which leaves us in the same position as a distributed addin.

So it looks like, based on the answers and comments to this post so far anyway, the only option to store my Global settings is in a separate file, on a network drive, probably sitting in the same folder as the addin itself. I'd be interested in the comments if someone has another way we haven't already touched on?